# I am getting below error while installing cocoapods can anyone give solutions to fix that same

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

[image]

I have build ios via flutter sdk but runner.workspace cannot install cocoapods.so i cannot run that runner project.if you have any solutions.kindly reply that forum. Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your ruby version by

```html
ruby -v
```

. If you have older version of ruby then update it using

```js
gem update --system
```

If you still cannot install cocoapods then install gem in a directory in which you have write access

```js
gem install -n pathtodirectorywithwriteaccess --user-install
```